Interpolation by an entire function with decay requirement
Suppose that $0<b<1$ is a real number. I'm interested in whether there exists an entire function $f(z)$ which decays faster than any exponential $e^{c|\Re(z)|}$ along horizontal lines $\Re(z)\rightarrow\pm\infty$ with $\Im(z)$ fixed, and takes the value $f(inb + im/b)=1$ for all non-negative integers $n,m$.
Apologies in advance if this is too elementary for MO -- happy to be pointed towards any standard references where this kind of interpolation problem is discussed!

@AlexandreEremenko: Why is there no such function in the irrational case? (Did you overlook the condition that $m,n\ge 0$?)

@AlexandreEremenko: I think the OP asks whether there is a function $f$ vanishing at the specified points and satisfying $|f(x+iy)|\le C(k,y)e^{-k|x|}$ for all $k>0$, $y\in\mathbb R$.

Thanks @AlexandreEremenko -- it's indeed the case $b^2$ irrational which I'm interested in, and the question is whether a function satisfying the conditions above exists. How do you see the non-existence in this case?

@Christian Remling: yes I overlooked the non-negativity condition.

Such functions exist. To construct one, first prepare
auxiliary entire functions $f_k$. Let $z_k$ be the enumeration of your sequence of interpolation nodes,
$$\{ imb+in/b:\; m,n\in\mathbf{Z}_{\geq 0}\}$$
ordered by absolute values.
Our functions $f_k$ will
have the following properties:
$$
\begin{align}
f_k(z_j) & =0, & j\neq k,\label{1}\tag{1}\\
f_k(z_k) & =1, & \label{2}\tag{2}\\
|f_k(z)| &\leq 2^{-k}, &|z|\leq |z_k|/2,\label{3}\tag{3}\\
|f_k(z)| & \leq 2^{-k}|e^{-z^2}|, &|\arg z|\leq \pi/5\label{4}\tag{4}.
\end{align}
$$
Once we have such functions, your function will be
$$f=\sum_k f_k.$$
Convergence of the series on compact subsets of the plane follows from \eqref{3},
interpolation property from \eqref{1}, \eqref{2}, and faster than exponential decrease on horizontal lines from \eqref{4}.
To construct $f_k$, first consider the canonical product $g$ with simple zeros at $z_j$. (It can be chosen of genus $2$ but this is irrelevant.) Then put
$$h_k(z)=\frac{g(z)}{g'(z_k)(z-z_k)},$$
so that $h_k$ has properties \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}.
Now multiply $h_k$ on auxiliary functions to achieve \eqref{3} and \eqref{4}:
$$f_k(z)=h_k(z)e^{n_k(z_k^2-z^2)},$$
where $n_k$ are some very large numbers.
It is clear that we preserved properties \eqref{1}, \eqref{2}.
On the other hand, $\max_{|z|\leq r}|e^{-z^2}|$ is attained at $z=z_k$, therefore the function $\exp(z_k^2-z^2)$ has modulus less than $1$ in the disk
$|z|<|z_k|/2$, and less than $|e^{-z^2}|<1$ in the sector $|\arg z|\leq\pi/5$. So raising it to a sufficiently large power $n_k$ we achieve \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}.
In the case when $b^2$ is rational, one does not need this custom-made construction, and one can simply refer to the general result on interpolation, see, for example B. Ya. Levin, Distribution of zeros of entire functions, Theorem 11 in Chapter IV (MR156975, Zbl 0152.06703). It requires the set of interpolation nodes to be an $R$-set in Levin's terminology, and this is granted for your set iff $b^2$ is rational.
Remarks. Unlike my construction, Levin's theorem gives a growth estimate for $f$. I suspect that one can achieve it in the general case, but the estimate will depend on the arithmetic nature of $b^2$.
On the other hand, the construction I proposed gives a much more general result, since I use almost no information about the nodes $z_k$ and about values at the nodes. So it works for more or less arbitrary sequence which is disjoint from sectors where the function is supposed to decrease.

Thank you @AlexandreEremenko -- this is great, and satisfyingly explicit!

@Daniele Tampieri: thanks for teaching me how to allign formula labels.

You are welcome, Alexandre. In those year I've been contributing to this Q&A site I've been learning so much and I'm glad to know that I' able to give something back.

@Daniele Tampieri: one minor detail: why does it put dots around formula references like .(3).? Can this be avoided?

This can be avoided, but not on the StackExchange, as it is an option of the $\LaTeX$ package hyperref furthermore embedded in Math Jax. Indeed, these are not points but is the graphical effect of the underscore signaling the presence of an hyperlink: notice the difference between \ref{3} and \eqref{3} in the text.
